# Type error for undefined property of imported component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is just a simple unit test, calling a Component with two SubComponents, which should be mocked.
The first mock is working as expected:

```
import { MockComponent } from '@app/mocks'

jest.mock('../Sub1', () => () => <div>mocked</div>) // working
jest.mock('../Sub2', () => MockComponent) // undefined property?

describe('Test', () => {
  test('should pass', () => {
    render(<Component />)
  })
})
```

The second one gives me this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'MockComponent' of undefined

   8 | 
   9 | jest.mock('../Sub1', () => () => <div>mocked</div>)
> 10 | jest.mock('../Sub2', () => MockComponent)
```

Why is the property undefined?

**@app/mocks**

```
import React, { ReactElement } from 'react'

const MockStyle = {}
const MockComponent = (): ReactElement => <div>mocked</div>

export { MockStyle, MockComponent }
```